# Error while uploading a text file in a bucket in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a normal text file in a bucket in google cloud storage.Till yesterday it was working file. But today when i am trying to upload a file, its giving me error. I was inspecting the request through firebug and it is showing me "Unsupported Media Type". I am simply using upload button from the cloud console (Windows). Can anybody help me to find out the problem?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: There was a temporary issue this morning for uploads through the cloud.google.com/console web interface for Google Cloud Storage, it should be resolved now.